# How can I convert a 3D SBS video to individual left side video and right side video?

Tags: video, 3d, standards-converter

Let’s suppose I have a 3D SBS video and I want to convert it such that I get two video files, one for left side video and one for the right. How can I do it? Is it possible to do so programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free commandline tool to do this.

```
ffmpeg -i sbs.mkv -filter_complex "split[l][r];[l]stereo3d=sbsl:ml[left];[r]stereo3d=sbsl:mr[right]" -map [left] -map 0:a -c:a copy left.mkv -map [right] -map 0:a -c:a copy right.mkv
```

Comment: how do l till it where the fill is

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to make a comment on the selected answer, but if you're using a version of ffmpeg with GPU support, you can use the GPU to render the output way faster. This is what I used. I don't know if all the settings are appropriate, especially the bitrate (I used a 45M bitrate in the input video and wasn't sure if halving that is appropriate for the outputs, so I didn't halve it). This took me a while to figure out, so I wanted to leave this here for others.

```
ffmpeg -i sbs.mkv -filter_complex "split[l][r];[l]stereo3d=sbsl:ml[left];[r]stereo3d=sbsl:mr[right]" -map [left] -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 45M left.mkv -map "[right]" -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 45M right.mkv
```

If you're using hsbs (half resolution side-by-side) like I am, you may also want to change sbsl to sbs2l so the video outputs are at "unsquished" aspect ratios.

```
ffmpeg -i sbs.mkv -filter_complex "split[l][r];[l]stereo3d=sbs2l:ml[left];[r]stereo3d=sbs2l:mr[right]" -map [left] -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 45M left.mkv -map "[right]" -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 45M right.mkv
```